# Why is it more useful to use inverse normal for qq plot?

Tags: stata, quantiles

Just ran this command `qnorm` in Stata to plot a qqplot of my data.

```
Y Axis = my observations
X Axis = quantiles of Normal distribution
```

However, Stata uses "inverse normal" as the X axis of the qqplot. Why is it more useful to use the inverse normal than the normal itself?

Comment: Note the command is `qnorm` not `qqnorm` as first posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small misunderstanding here: "inverse normal" in this context is just jargon for selected quantiles from the quantile function.

Fuller wording would be "inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function".

The first relevant line of the associated help file (accessible to all via https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?qnorm) gives a definition in other terms:

> `qnorm` plots the quantiles of *varname* against the quantiles of the
>   normal
>       distribution (Q-Q plot).

In general, as you say, a quantile-quantile plot necessarily plots quantiles versus quantiles.

I am not clear what else you're imagining that "inverse normal" could mean, however.

Comment: (+1) Possibly the OP had https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution in mind.

Comment: @whuber Good point, although I don't recall that distribution being called "inverse normal". Anything is possible....